# Can I share Wiki between the projects?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I have some projects in Azure DevOps in one account.
I want to share Wiki between projects.
Can I share Wiki between projects.If so, please tell me the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I share Wiki between the projects?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such feature to share wiki between projects directly. Actually the wiki pages store as a md file in the wiki repository, so you could clone the repository in VS directly, then pull and push a md file from one repository to another repository. For more information, you could refer to this link:

[Clone and update wiki content offline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)

I would encourage you to create (or upvote) a [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) item:

[image]

Note: You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I can't share Wiki between projects, but can copy Wiki to another project.